# Does a woman's G-spot actually exist?

Tags: human-anatomy

Does a woman's G-spot actually exist? Are there any research studies?

Links:

- [G-spot (Gräfenberg spot)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-spot) at Wikipedia
- [U.S. gynaecologist says he has found the G-spot](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/health/article-2134752/Yes-does-exist-U-S-gynaecologist-says-G-spot-very-small.html)

Comment: The links you provide contain all the material you could likely get in an answer here. There's hence not really any use in asking here as you could just as well read the Wikipedia article and its linked resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The existence of the G-spot remains highly debated among researchers.  Two recent publications ([Hines 2001,](http://www.ajog.org/article/S0002-9378(01)15335-4/abstract) [Kilchevsky et al. 2012](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1743-6109.2011.02623.x/abstract;jsessionid=9A8FFD67816AD8F62367685771328013.f02t02)) review studies of the so-called G-spot and conclude the evidence is too inconsistent to claim its definite existence.  [Foldes and Buisson (2009)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1743-6109.2009.01231.x/abstract) argue that the G-spot is actually just a clitoris that is richly  innervated. This would be consistent with the reported variability of G-spot presence or absence due to natural variation in innervation among women. (This last statement is my hypothesis offered without citation).

As noted by @Armatus in the comments, a few minutes following some of the Wikipedia links to the scientific journals (not the BBC, CNN, pop news sites, etc.) would give you lots of information about the G-spot. Still, I thought you question was worth typing up a brief answer for the sake of completeness.

**Literature Cited**

Foldès, P. and O. Buisson. 2009. The clitoral complex: a dynamic sonographic study. The Journal of Sexual Medicine 6: 1223–31.

Hines T. 2001. The G-Spot: A modern gynecologic myth. American Journal of Obstetrics and Gynecology 185: 359–62.

Kilchevsky, A, et al. 2012. Is the Female G-Spot Truly a Distinct Anatomic Entity? Journal of Sexual Medicine. 719-726.